# Bulk de-RLE-compress TGA images

Tags: linux, compression, tga

I'm on Linux Mint 17.3 KDE and am having some issues with viewing and sorting a nearly 2.7GB collection of TGA images (mostly game textures). Apparently, GwenView and many other programs (notably excluding GIMP) don't cooperate with RLE compressed TGAs. How can I bulk decompress these images?

Answer (score 0):

So in the directory, in a terminal

`for x in ./*.tga; do convert $x.tga -compress None decompressed_$x.tga; done`

This may work, as it relies on imagemagick being installed and is based off an answer about decompressing png's [here](https://superuser.com/questions/454539/convert-image-to-uncompressed-png-from-the-command-line)

Also, you can test for just one file first, using this:

`convert blah.tga -compress None decompressed_blah.tga`

Then check 'decompressed_blah.tga' to see if the file works/is usable.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. A single TGA decompressed with this method still fails to load in GwenView, even while the same image decompressed in GIMP and exported does.